# How to return a list of the following position if Boolean is True while using lambda, map, and list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I have a list of names and after each name is a number. Like this

```
l = ["Bob", 4, "Rob", 5, "Sam", 6, "Bob", 5]
```

I would like to return a list of numbers that correspond to a given name, by only using lambda, map, list or filter.

For example, if I were to use the name Bob with `list = ["Bob",4,"Rob",5,"Sam",6,"Bob",5]`, my output would be

`[4,5]`

I think I understand most of lambda, I just can't get it to return what I want it too.

`mx = list(map(lambda x: l[x+1] if x == name, l))`

I am getting this error.
`Syntax Error: invalid syntax: <string>, line 14, pos 29`

Comment: `l[x+1] if x == name` isn't a syntactically valid expression. `lambda` functions only take expressions. Anyway, `map` doesn't seem appropriate here, at least not on that list, because whatever function you provide `map` will be *applied to every element*. You probably want to group your list's elements into pairs first, then map a function that works on those pairs...

Comment: Also, just think about what would happen if this did work: `l[x+1] if x == name` so if `x == 'Bob'`, then you are going to index into `l` using `l["Bob" + 1]`, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Where are you getting that list in the first place? If each name is meant to be associated with the following number, something more explicit like `[("Bob", 4), ("Rob", 5), ...]` would be more natural. (It's also easy to get: `zip(l[0::2], l[1::2])`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can run through values at even indexes and output the value at the next index when it matches the name:

```
result = [l[i+1] for i in range(0,len(l),2) if l[i] == "Bob"]
```

If you're allowed to use enumerate, this can be a bit more concise (assuming none of the odd indexes contain a matching string):

```
result = [l[i+1] for i,n in enumerate(l) if n == 'Bob' ]
```

or using zip()

```
result = [v for n,v in zip(l,l[1:]) if n == 'Bob']
```

Answer (score 0):

Reconstruct the list into a list of tuples; then a list comprehension is trivial:

```
items = [number for (name, number) in zip(l[0::2], l[1::2]) if name == "Bob"]
```